# Android Application Not Showing Anything

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I'm trying to create a basic audio player with Play/Pause and a slider based on this tutorial: http://mrbool.com/how-to-play-audio-files-in-android-with-a-seekbar-feature-and-mediaplayer-class/28243

Everything compiles properly however nothing shows up in the activity on either emulator or device. Device api level 18 and AVD api level 19

MainActivity.java

```
package com.ex.highline;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    SeekBar seek_bar;
    Button play_button, pause_button;
    MediaPlayer player;
    TextView text_shown;
    Handler seekHandler = new Handler();

public void onClick(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    seekUpdate();

    /* Initialize all views */
    seek_bar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seek_bar);

    play_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.play_button);

    pause_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pause_button);

    text_shown = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_shown);

    play_button.setOnClickListener((android.view.View.OnClickListener) this);
    pause_button.setOnClickListener((android.view.View.OnClickListener) this);

    player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.money);

    seek_bar.setMax(player.getDuration());

}

Runnable run = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run(){

        seekUpdate();
    }
};


public void seekUpdate() {

    seek_bar.setProgress(player.getCurrentPosition());
    seekHandler.postDelayed(run, 1000);
}

public void onClick(View view){
    switch (view.getId()){
    case R.id.play_button:
        text_shown.setText("Playing...");
        player.start();
        break;
    case R.id.pause_button:
        player.pause();
        text_shown.setText("Paused...");
    }
}



}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_shown"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
    android:text=""
    android:textSize="42sp" />

<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seek_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/pause_button"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/play_button"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/play_button"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/text_shown"
    android:text="@string/pause" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/play_button"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/text_shown"
    android:layout_below="@+id/seek_bar"
    android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/play" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: `public void onClick(Bundle savedInstanceState) {` is wrong

Comment: How would you suggest it be modified?

Comment: The first thing to check is the app config file, could you post the AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: replace the first onClick( with onCreate(

Comment: public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

Comment: Ah thanks. I'm embarrassed but that did the trick!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is two changes:

**1)** `OncLick` ==> `onCreate`

2) put `seekUpdate();` at the `end of onCreate method` (cauz you have the var play)**

```
  public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    SeekBar seek_bar;
    Button play_button, pause_button;
    MediaPlayer player;
    TextView text_shown;
    Handler seekHandler = new Handler();

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { // <== change here 

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    /* Initialize all views */
    seek_bar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seek_bar);

    play_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.play_button);

    pause_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pause_button);

    text_shown = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_shown);

    play_button.setOnClickListener((android.view.View.OnClickListener) this);
    pause_button.setOnClickListener((android.view.View.OnClickListener) this);

    player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.test);

    seek_bar.setMax(player.getDuration());
    seekUpdate();  // <==== change here
}
// the rest of code
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In Android the activities are shown responding to intents.
When you click on an Android App icon in your mobile you are launching the action android.intent.action.MAIN with the category android.intent.category.LAUNCHER so... if you want to see the activity you should make sure that you have something like this in your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity">

        <!-- intent filters -->
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Where .MainActivity is the class name of your activity with the app package as prefix.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.ex.highline"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
```

So... the app package + the activity main are the activity complete class name that you want to start (when you click on the app icon).

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to comment but it was resolved by the prescriptions above. I'm just dumb and used onClick() instead of onCreate().

Comment: I see after I post it, anyway I hope I gave you some useful information, cheers.